Ethereum Hardhat Testing on sepolia testnet ,it could not stop
I am running my test code in the hardhat environment.
my test code is like this
describe("[TEST]FundMe Contract", async () => {
    it("testing", async () => {
        console.log(`hello`);
    });

    console.log(`iamhere`);
});

when I run the following script,
yarn hardhat test
I get the right result
$ /home/tigerjoe/hh-fcc/hardhat-fundme/node_modules/.bin/hardhat test
iamhere

[TEST]FundMe Contract
hello
✔ testing

but when I test my code on sepolia testnet with following script
yarn hardhat test --network sepolia
the script just could not stop with the following out put
iamhere

[TEST]FundMe Contract
hello

it seems the code stucks in somewhere i dont know.
please give me some hint what should i do to solve this problem. thanks very much
